# Should a variable be created when an object is created merely to call a single method?

Tags: java

Imagine a scenario where we need to create an object only for a single method call. Which of the following is a better coding practice and why:

1. **Putting the object in a variable:**

   ```
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   int val = foo.getVal();
   ```

   *Advantage:* In case of exception handling we could isolate exceptions in constructor vs those in `getVal()` function.
   *Disadvantage:* An extra variable.
2. **Calling the method directly on the result:**

   ```
   int val = new Foo().getVal();
   ```

   *Advantage:* No need to have an extra variable lying around.
   *Disadvantage:* If an exception occurs, it's more difficult to determine whether the constructor or method threw it.

Comment: Use option 2 and create a static class and a static function.       Why: What you're describing sounds like a utility function (storing state isn't necessary) so a constructor really isn't needed.

Comment: Your constructors shall not throw exceptions.

Comment: Exception handling has nothing to do with it. The stack trace would tell you where the exception occurred.

Comment: An advantage to #1 is debugging. `Step Into` is very cumbersome with chained calls.  Option #1 allows you to place your breakpoint at the precise point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't need the reference, use option two.  It lets the memory be reclaimed by the garbage collector sooner.

On the other hand, if you really don't need the reference, your method should probably be `static` to begin with.  I know that whenever I see something like `new Foo().getVal()` in my production environment, I immediately go to the `getVal()` definition and find all references.  Ninety-nine times out of a hundred, it ought to be a `static` method.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the optimization done by JIT they would very likely have the same performance. Overall, the second option is slightly more readable and terse.